# Space travel and time dilation

Tags: special-relativity, space-travel

I want to know how long it takes, from an observer in a spaceship moving at constant velocity $v=\beta c$, to cover a distance $d$.

From a stationnary observer outside, the spaceship goes at a velocity $v$ and so he will say that it took an amount of time given by $d/v$. However as he looks into the spaceship the clock inside "tics" slower and sees that this clock measures a time given by $d/\gamma v$.

The observer inside the spaceship however sees its clock running normally and going at the same velocity but he sees the distance go from $d$ to $d/\gamma$ therefore he measures a time given by $d/\gamma v$.

To me the it seems correct to say that the observer in the spaceship has travelled for a time $d/\gamma v$ in his frame of reference, but is this exact or are there missing things?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok thank you. I thought it was just that I had the impression something was missing.